# Notification on questions on which a user comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, questions

Whenever I comment on a question like to post a fiddle or give more explanation on the problem statement, unless the OP does not mention my name I do not receive the comment what the OP or others might have commented. Can a feature be added for the same as I would be interested in that question and if I had commented from my mobile their should be a way that I get the response for that question.